# Getting "java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore" format after conversion of .jks file stream to utf-8 encoded string and back to stream

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am getting the uploaded .jks file as input in inputstream format. I am converting it into UTF-8 encoded string and storing it in String variable which inturn i intend to store in DB.
To convert inputstream to UTF-8 encoded string i am using :  `keyStoreString = IOUtils.toString(inputstream, "UTF-8")`

When i again convert it to inputstream to load same in keystore i am getting the exception

```
    KeyStore ks = null;
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    char[] passwordArray = password.toCharArray();
    ks.load(IOUtils.toInputStream(keyStoreString, Constants.UTF_ENCODING),
            passwordArray);
```

When i directly use the inputstream then the code is working, means the inputstream i am getting is correct.
Can anyone please tell me if i am doing something wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not converting it to a UTF-8 encoded string. You are converting it *from* UTF-8 to a string. Since it's not actually UTF-8, converting it from UTF-8 to anything is a silly thing to do that will probably corrupt it irreversibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am converting it into UTF-8 encoded string and storing it in String variable

Don't do that!

Some byte sequences *cannot* be translated to characters. Instead, store as a string format expressly designed to represent binary, such as Base64.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The following worked for me
keyStoreString = Base64.encodeBase64String(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));  
  
and for decoding  
  
ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(keyStoreString)), passwordArray)